# odp.net bulk copy with c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I want to use odp.net's OracleBulkCopy class to copy data from Microsoft Sql Server database to an Oracle database. I have a table with around 2M rows and 100 columns. I am having problem with memory allocations. Following code seems to be allocating memory and never releasing, till it gets a cannot allocate memory exception.

I used a very similar code to transfer data from Oracle to MSSQL server using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy function and never had this kind of problem.

```
 using (SqlConnection sourceConnection =
               new SqlConnection(sourceConn))
        {

            sourceConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand commandSourceData = new SqlCommand(
              sourceSQL, sourceConnection);

            commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = 1000000;


            using (OracleConnection destinationConnection =
                       new OracleConnection(connStr))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();
                using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new OracleBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {

                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;  
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(commandSourceData.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess));

                }
            }
        }
```

When I check the memory allocations these two functions seems to be using most of the memory:

-System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(int32) (70%)
-Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetBytes(valuetype System.Decimal, native int) (20%)

Does anybody have any idea about the cause of the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: High amounts of allocations are expected as you're pulling the entire database through the managed heap. Find out what is *holding* memory alive. What are the roots? Let's hope it is not the Oracle code because then you're out of luck.

Comment: Why are you using the .NET sql client? Have you considered just purely using the Oracle adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to explicitly Close() and Dispose() your ODP.NET objects. The garbage collector doesn't know about memory being held by unmanaged code.